# how to get all values of particular TextView of listView? -Android

Tags: android, listview

i have made ListView with three columns 'item','qty','rate' i get this entries from the user and i have made the listview work perfectly but i want to get all the values of the 'rate' column and add them for the net amount.

Here is my android code:

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_list);
    populateList();
    adapter = new listviewAdapter(List.this, list);
    lview.setAdapter(adapter);
}


private void populateList() {
    HashMap temp = new HashMap();
    list = new ArrayList<HashMap>();

    item = etItem.getText().toString();
    qty = etQty.getText().toString();
    rate = etRate.getText().toString();

    temp.put(FIRST_COLUMN, "1");
    temp.put(SECOND_COLUMN, item);
    temp.put(THIRD_COLUMN, qty);
    temp.put(FOURTH_COLUMN, rate);
    list.add(temp);
```

}

I tried out this method below but it only toast the first value.But i want to get all the values under the rate column and add them up for the net-amount.

```
   public void get() {
       StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
       for(int i=0; i<adapter.getCount(); i++) {
           String a = ((TextView) findViewById(R.id.FourthText)).getText().toString();
           adapter.getItem(i).toString();
           sb.append(a);
           sb.append("\n");
       }
       text = sb.toString();
       Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), text, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
   }
```

Comment: Why can't you interate over the list variable you made which should have all the items?

Comment: @caiolopes i cant do that because i have made button to delete some rows from list so there will an update in ListView.

Comment: I would recommend you to remove from the list too when you remove from the listview, so you can keep track of what is happening. And it will make easier to calculate the net amount by looping trough the list.

Comment: yea but even i need the data to be assembled in the database, anyway i need to get the datas from the ListView. i'm still searching for i need some help

Comment: Whenever you need to work in bunch of values at that time define on pojo as class for getter and setter and then use list of that class and use values from that is better way for flexibility and faster performance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think this might help you.

```
private int GrandTotal(ListView list) {
int sum=0;
for (int i = 0; i < list.getCount(); i++) {
    View v = list.getChildAt(i);
    TextView rate = (TextView) v.findViewById(R.id.rate);
    sum = sum + Integer.parseInt(rate.getText().toString() )
}
return sum;
```

}

:)

Answer (score 1):

```
public void getTotalRate() {

    int totalRate = 0;
    for (int i = 0; i < list.size(); i++) {
        HashMap temp = list.get(i);
        /// here fourth column is rate
        int rate = (int) temp.get(FOURTH_COLUMN);
        totalRate = totalRate + rate;
    }

    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "total rate=" + totalRate, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
}
```

Comment: i get NullPointerException at the line "  int rate = temp.get("FOURTH_COLUMN");".. what i can change in it .?

Comment: @iamRaja i just realized that you are using FOURTH_COLUMN as a variable not a string so I have updated the code.

Comment: @Arsian any other idea.?

Comment: you might need to add   @Override
    public HashMap getItem(int position) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        return this.items.get(position);
    }
in you adapter

Comment: @iamRaja I have updated the best answer,, please mark it accepted if it does any help to you .